# Using regular expression in python to find a number between 540-600

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am just a beginner in python and I am using regex to find a number between 540-600

and have written following script but this doesn't works :

```
import re
import sys

def valid_num(num):
    print num
    p = re.match (r'^[5-6]\d\d', str(num))
    return bool(p) and all(map(lambda n: 540<= int(n)<=600, p.groups()))

a = 699
print valid_num(a)
```

Comment: What you're doing can be achieved in a simpler way... Why use regex?

Comment: `return 540 <= num <= 600`? Given that you have to do that anyway, why bother with a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a regex that matches only numbers between 540 and 600 with the following part:

```
5[4-9]\d|600
```

So the regex consists out of two possibilities: `5[4-9]\d` and `600`. The `5[4-9]\d` matches any number between 540 and 599 since it starts with a `5` followed by a digit between 4 and 9 and a digit between 0 and 9. `600` matches the 600 number.

Furthermore you probably want to use word boundaries `\b` to make sure you do not match `56900`. So:

```
\b(?:5[4-9]\d|600)\b
```

Or in case the string should *only* contain the number, you should use start and end anchors:

```
^(?:5[4-9]\d|600)$
```

So that would result in:

```
import re

rgx540600 = re.compile(r'^(?:5[4-9]\d|600)$')

def valid_num(num):
    return bool(rgx540600.match(str(num)))
```

That being said, it is usually not a good idea to do such verifications with a regex. Regex are usually more for syntactical validation whereas for semantical validation, other tools are usually of better use.

Comment: man where were you all these years , become my teacher and teach me python every day of my life ... than i will ask you a question every day and that will keep both of ur's dementia away

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use regex, I would suggest you something like:

`^600|[5][4-9]\d`

It will find 600, or 5 followed by a number from 4 to 9, plus another digit